# Why is it flagging me error when deserializing a list of objects?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

I have a WebApi, where there is a method that returns a Json, I must consume that method from an Android Xamarin App, the method is as follows:

```
 public string GetData(DateTime Del, DateTime Al, Guid id)
        {

            List<TablaVales> LstTemp = new List<TablaVales>();
            List<TablaVales> tableV = new List<TablaVales>();
            string conexion = "data source = snare.arvixe.com; initial catalog = ****; user id = ****; password = ****";
            oLogin myLogin = new oLogin();

           cTripleDES des = new cTripleDES();
            String sQuery = String.Format("SELECT promVales.llave, promVales.NumeroVale, promVales.llaveProm, LTRIM(RTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Numero, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Nombre1, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Nombre2, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Apellido1, ''))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(crmCustomers.Apellido1, ''))))) AS Nombre, crmCustomers.DireccionCompleta, CrmCustomers.Telefono, CASE WHEN promVales.Status = 1 THEN 'Asignado' WHEN promVales.Status = 2 THEN 'Extraviado' WHEN promVales.Status = 3 THEN 'Utilizado' WHEN promVales.Status = 4 THEN 'Suspendido por Depto. de Crédito' WHEN promVales.Status = 5 THEN 'Cancelado' ELSE 'Este vale no puede ser utilizado' END AS Status, promVales.FechaAsigna, aztiendas.NOMBRE AS TiendaAsigna, promVales.FechaUso, aztiendas_1.NOMBRE AS TiendaUso, Personas.Nombre AS NombreUsuarioUso, LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login.Nombres, '') + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login.Apellidos, ''))))) AS AsignadoPor, LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login_1.Nombres, '') + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(login_1.Apellidos, ''))))) AS UsuarioVenta, promVales.Caja, promVales.Operacion, promMotivos.Nombre AS MotivoValeExtraviado, promMotivos_1.Nombre AS MotivoValeCancelado, promVales.Monto, promVales.MontoAutoriza, promVales.Anticipo FROM promVales LEFT JOIN CrmCustomers ON promVales.llaveProm = crmCustomers.id LEFT JOIN azTiendas ON promVales.llaveTiendaAsigna = azTiendas.llave LEFT JOIN azTiendas AS azTiendas_1 ON promVales.llaveTiendaUso = azTiendas_1.llave LEFT JOIN Personas ON promVales.llaveClienteUso = Personas.llave LEFT JOIN login ON promVales.llaveUsuarioAsigna = login.llave LEFT JOIN login AS login_1 ON promVales.llaveUsuarioVenta = login_1.llave LEFT JOIN promMotivos ON promVales.llaveMotivoPerdido = promMotivos.llave LEFT JOIN promMotivos AS promMotivos_1 ON promVales.llaveMotivoCancela = promMotivos.llave WHERE(DATEADD(DD, 0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, promVales.FechaAsigna)) BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}') AND promVales.llaveProm = '{2}'",
                                          String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", Del), String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", Al), "AF8257A3-C284-4682-8DB5-6E20AE05C747" );
            DataSet ds = bdBase.bdDataset(conexion, sQuery);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TablaVales tv = new TablaVales();
                    tv.NumeroVale = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NumeroVale"].ToString());
                    tv.Status = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Status"].ToString();
                    tv.MotivoValeExtraviado = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MotivoValeExtraviado"].ToString();
                    tv.FechaAsigna =DateTime.Parse( ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FechaAsigna"].ToString());
                    tv.TiendaAsigna = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TiendaAsigna"].ToString());
                    tv.AsignadoPor = (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AsignadoPor"].ToString());

                    tableV.Add(tv);
                    LstTemp = tableV;
                }
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LstTemp.ToList());
            return json;
        }
```

and these are the data that the JSON throws to me, I think that until now everything well
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Here my Xamarin Android app

```
 public void Rest()
    {
        try
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/Values/");
            var request = new RestRequest("GetData", Method.GET);
            request.Timeout = 300000;
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddParameter("Del", btnDel.Text);
            request.AddParameter("Al", btnAl.Text);
            //request.AddParameter("llaveEmp", llaveEmp);
            request.AddParameter("id", id);
            var temp = client.Execute(request).Content;
            List<TablaVales> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TablaVales>>(temp);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

But in the line "List lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject> (temp); dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;" I throw the following error:

> "Error converting value
>   "[{"NumeroVale":107,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   {"NumeroVale":43,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se
>   perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":45,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se
>   perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":204,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":148,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"}]"  to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AndroidPP.Controller.TablaVales]'.
>   Path '', line 1, position 29775."

Any idea why he sends that mistake? or if you could help me find my mistake, thank you.

And add the class TablaVales

```
public class TablaVales
{ 
        public int NumeroVale { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string MotivoValeExtraviado { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaAsigna { get; set; }
        public string TiendaAsigna { get; set; }
        public string AsignadoPor { get; set; }
}
```

and it should be mentioned that the class is the same in both the WebApi, as in the Mobile App

Now i will add the json in text format

> [{"NumeroVale":107,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":109,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":119,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":126,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":108,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":55,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":129,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":102,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":138,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":113,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":121,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":100,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":105,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":200,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":122,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":201,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":116,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":115,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":128,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":123,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":35,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":52,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":53,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":5,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":47,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":54,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":111,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":34,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":51,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":104,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":37,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":7,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":120,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":31,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":125,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":40,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":136,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":38,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":44,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":32,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":103,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":42,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":114,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":64,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":66,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":67,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":50,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":9,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:29","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":59,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":60,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":41,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":46,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":48,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":49,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":112,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":523,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":507,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":10,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:29","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":101,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":110,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":118,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":144,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":106,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":124,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:08","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":141,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":143,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":142,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":145,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":127,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":117,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":39,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":203,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":205,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":525,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":513,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":514,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":516,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":515,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":510,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":519,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:38:21","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":512,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-14T09:07:59","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":140,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":146,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":151,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":152,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-13T08:47:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":43,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se
>   perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":45,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se
>   perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":204,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":206,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":1,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":2,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":3,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":96,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":97,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":4,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":6,"Status":"Cancelado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":8,"Status":"Utilizado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-09T19:47:28","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin
>   Cruz"}]

Comment: Your WebApi returns JSON embedded in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Check your service return data.
the issue is with the data.
i saw data pattern mismatch

{"NumeroVale":43,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":45,"Status":"Extraviado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"Se perdió","FechaAsigna":"2016-06-10T20:08:07","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},{"NumeroVale":204,"Status":"Asignado","MotivoValeExtraviado":"","FechaAsigna":"2016-07-06T07:58:14","TiendaAsigna":"","AsignadoPor":"Martin Cruz"},